# How to merge two functions into one in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, merge

I want to merge two functions into one.

The functions are

```
 data Dice = Stone Char deriving (Show, Eq)

 calculateScore :: [Dobbelsteen]  -> Int
 calculateScore xs = sum[giveValueDice x | x <- xs]

 giveValueDice :: Dice -> Int
 giveValueDice (Stone d) = if d == 'W' then 5 else digitToInt d
```

Normally, I would just copy one line into the first function en change a little bit to make the syntax correct. But here I am kinda lost how to do this

Comment: What do you want the new function to do? What is `Dobbelsteen`? What is `giveValueDice`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already noticed, you can't just directly inline here; the reason for this is that you're pattern matching on `Stone` in `giveValueDice`. This pattern matching can be moved inside the right side of the list comprehension:

```
 calculateScore :: [Dobbelsteen]  -> Int
 calculateScore xs = sum[if d == 'W' then 5 else digitToInt d | (Stone d) <- xs]
```

Another method for merging these two functions is using a `where` clause, which 'merges' one function into another while keeping them distince:

```
 calculateScore :: [Dobbelsteen]  -> Int
 calculateScore xs = sum[giveValueDice x | x <- xs]
   where
     giveValueDice :: Dice -> Int
     giveValueDice (Stone d) = if d == 'W' then 5 else digitToInt d
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it and it works, so really perfect answer :)